# Can I play a sound or display things in Ubuntu on mobile device?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, graphics, mobile

Some time ago I installed Termux terminal on my phone just to have some fun with it. Later I discovered I can have an Ubuntu distribution running with it so I decided to give it a try.

It's working nicely but all things that need to display something or play some sort of sound do not work. I suppose my Ubuntu is just trying to do the exact thing it would on a PC but things are a little bit diffrent on mobile.

I can hovewer play sound and display things when using Termux without Ubuntu so things like VLC work for example. I just wonder if it's possible to fix this issue or develop some workaround.